# Omniauth facebook how to set up properly configs in facebook apps dashboard?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise, omniauth-facebook

I know this question has been asked many times but none of them helped me.

I'm trying to make a login with facebook to my website, but getting an error:

```
{"error":{"message":"Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"DV9+XV2aZn5"}}
```

I have the following configs in my facebook apps dashboard:

[image]
[image]

Seems I'm missing something with setting up URLs but can't figure out what.

**Update**

**app/models/customer.rb**

```
devise :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: [:facebook]
```

Comment: Are you using devise/omniauth for your logins?

Comment: yes, there's a tag if you don't see

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to be a bug in omniauth-facebook gem
Refer on this thread for this bug 
https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook/issues/220
Also here is the fix
https://github.com/gioblu/omniauth-facebook/commit/eff97bfae32f72821cbccf0b48b78351e41eb585

Comment: How do I access the omniauth library? I don't see it in my rails app folder.

Comment: I was using devise for facebook and google and they're both not working with the same issue. Is this because I updated my gems?

Answer (score 0):

For devise omniauth your call back will have a url structure like:

```
http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback
```

Instead of just the http://localhost:3000 that you are showing in your screenshot.

Comment: "Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains."

Comment: this is what I got when I changed "Valid Oauth redirect URIs" value to "http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback"

Comment: @user2931706 add, localhost, to app domains, under the basic area.

Comment: Yes, just development

Comment: Do you have a setup similar to this? http://sourcey.com/rails-4-omniauth-using-devise-with-twitter-facebook-and-linkedin/

Comment: followed devise setup https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview and now Im also getting this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using devise and facebook omniauth then Valid OAuth redirect URIs is:

```
http://localhost:3000/users/auth/facebook/callback
```

http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback is used when devise is not used just omniauth is used.

my site is online but uri can be seen in [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzx8B.png)